# FastAPI, работа с базами данных

Tags: python, fastapi

При запуске в терминале команды: alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Database creation"
выдает ошибку sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected
Как это исправить? Может пакет установить?

Comment: Похоже sqlalchemy модель неправильно описана. Нужно посмотреть что там.

Comment: Каким образом? Расскажите подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: Не знаю. Как я и написал, нужно посмотреть что там. А кода вы не предоставили.